# RazorEngine configuration error, templateSettings

Tags: vb.net, razorengine, web-config

I'm trying to use RazorEngine from VB, and I'm stuck on an issue with the configuration.

I have this is my web.config...

```
  <configSections>
    <section name="razorEngine" type="RazorEngine.Configuration.RazorEngineConfigurationSection, RazorEngine" requirePermission="false"/>
  </configSections>
  <razorEngine>
    <templateServices>
      <add name="myCustomTemplateService" language="VisualBasic"/>
    </templateServices>
  </razorEngine>
```

As far as I can see from the documentation this looks correct. However when I try to run my code, I get the following error...

"Unrecognized element 'add'."

It doesn't like this bit...

```
<add name="myCustomTemplateService" language="VisualBasic"/>
```

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated. I'm stumped. All the examples I've found online appear to show that I'm doing it the correct way.

Update:

I've changed my Web.config to...

```
<razorEngine>
    <templateServices>
        <service name="service" language="VisualBasic" />
    </templateServices>
</razorEngine>
```

The config no longer errors, however RazorEngine appears to be ignoring it, as it gives the following error when I try to parse a template...

```
Unable to compile template. Unexpected character '$'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're reading pre-v3 docs on how to configure that stuff in the web.config.  Unfortunately, I don't see any documentation for RazorEngine configuration for verson 3 and up.  But you can read the source directly on GitHub, and it looks like they've changed those config elements around. [Here's](https://github.com/Antaris/RazorEngine/blob/master/src/Core/RazorEngine.Core/Configuration/Xml/TemplateServiceConfigurationElementCollection.cs) the source on the templateServices element.  It looks like, at a minimum, child elements are no longer added using an "add" node.  They are now added using a "service" node (`AddItemName = "service"`).

Comment: Thanks, I'd actually found this in the source code also. However it still doesn't work. The config no longer errors, but it's once again saying..."Unable to compile template. Unexpected character '$'", which is the same as it does without anything defined in the Web.config.

Comment: I can only assume that RazorEngine simply doesn't support VB. I've been able to get RazorTemplates to work, so I'll just have to use that instead.

Comment: It sounds like there's something that it doesn't like about the template. You could post the template contents, but technically speaking that should probably be the beginning of a separate question.  I think the specific question that you posted above about the configuration error that you were facing is now resolved, wouldn't you say? Don't forget to mark the answer as accepted if it helped you.

Comment: Yes that's a good idea, I'll create a new question. The template works though from C#, so I'm not confident that this is the problem.